# Elasticsearch 6.0 Removal of mapping types - Alternatives

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

### Background

I migrating my ES index into ES version 6. I currenly stuck because ES6 removed the using on "_type" field.

### Old Implementation (ES2)

My software has many users (>100K). Each user has at least one document in ES. So, the hierarchy looks like this:

```
INDEX  ->  TYPE      -> Document
myindex->  user-123  -> document-1
```

The key point here is with this structure I can easily remove all the document of specific user.

```
DELETE /myindex/user-123
```

(Delete all the document of specific user, with a single command)

### The problem

"_type" is no longer supported by ES6.

### Possible solution

Instead of using `_type`, use the index name as `USER-ID`. So my index will looks like:

```
"user-123" -> "static-name" -> document
```

Delete user is done by delete index (instead of delete `type` in previous implementation).

### Questions:

- My first worry is about the amount of index and performance: Having like 1M indexes is something that acceptable in terms of performance? don't forget I have to search on them frequently.
- Most of my users has small amount of documents stored in ES. Is that make sense to hold a shard, which should be expensive, for < 10 documents?
- My data architecture sounds reasonable for you?

Any other tip will be welcome!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not have one index per user, it's a waste of resources, especially if there are only 10 docs per user.

What I would do instead is to use [filtered aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered), one per user.

So the index would be named `users` and the type would be a static name, e.g. `doc`. For user 123, the documents of that user would all be stored in `users/doc/xyz` and in each document you need to add the user id, e.g.

```
PUT users/doc/xyz
{
   ...
   "userId": 123,
   ...
}
```

Then you can define a filtered alias for all documents of user 123, like this:

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "users",
                 "alias" : "user-123",
                 "filter" : { "term" : { "userId" : "123" } }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you need to delete all documents of user 123, then you can simply do it like this:

```
POST user-123/_delete_by_query?q=*
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Thanks! Does `filtered alias` consume a lot of resources? even if we talking about 1M aliases?

Comment: Aliases are stored in the cluster state, and the cluster state needs to be copied to every node of your cluster every time it changes. So, if you have 1M aliases, yes, that might have performance impacts, but it depends on many other factors. That's something you'd need to test on your specific setup. Maybe you don't have to create all aliases, but only a few, and create aliases on-demand whenever you need to query certain users.

Comment: If you've got the 1M alias issue you can just filter by the user name yourself, rather than rely on a filtered alias to do that filtering for you. The delete by query would just need to do a term query on the `userId` field like the alias does.

Comment: @Val what about `user-222` then ,  are you basically saying maps all `users-*` as alias's to the `index` ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik depending on your user count, that's one way... but maybe create a new thread to better explain your specific use case

Comment: @Val No No. Was just admiring ur brilliant answer haha , so essentially you've in a way cheated the system by bring the `user-123` on level up ( using alias ofcourse , also not actually got it up but kidda linked it to the index directly) ?

Comment: @Val also what is `q=*` ? is it absolutely needed ?

Comment: It's better to provide a query to `_delete_by_query` in order to not delete everything by accident

Answer (score 0):

Having these many indexes is definitely not a good approach. If your only concern to delete multiple documents with a single command. Then you can use [Delete by Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/docs-delete-by-query.html) API provided by ElasticSearch

You can introduce "subtype" attribute in all your document containing value for each document like "user-" value. So in your case, document would looks like.

```
{
  "attribute1":"value", 
  "subtype":"user-123"
}
```